# Did Africans defeat Europeans in battle between 1850 and 1950?

Tags: military, colonization, africa, ethiopia

The battle of Adwa was fought between Italians and Ethiopians in northern Ethiopia in 1896. The Italians were defeated  and it was the greatest victory for Africans. Were there any other battles where Africans defeated Europeans between 1850 and 1950?

Comment: Sources would improve this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One example of a clear and decisive European defeat is the [Battle of Isandlwana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Isandlwana) in 1879, during the [Anglo-Zulu War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Zulu_War). The British started taking the Zulus a lot more seriously after that, and won the war.

Answer (score 5):

An example in which the native forces were numerically inferior<sup>1</sup> the colonizing forces was the [Battle of Annual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Annual) in Morocco in 1924.

Not in Africa, but still part of the colonial efforts, in 1857 the [Indian Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857) managed to expel the British East India Company for two years.

---

<sup>1</sup>OTOH, the technological differences between the two forces were not as lopsided as it was in Isandlwana.

Answer (score 1):

[Basuto gun war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basuto_Gun_War) was the first defeat of an European power in a war against Africans

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added a link to the answer - I hope the OP doesn't mind. Although concise, I think the answer actually answers the question. A question asking for additional information that is not in the question would be closed as too basic, as it is already answered in Wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

[Afroblogger](http://theafroblogger.blogspot.com/2016/01/10-most-amazing-military-upsets-by.html?m=1) lists the greatest upsets by Africans against European armies

Comment: Links can change or pages can be removed, so it would improve this answer if you included the key details of the linked article here.

Comment: @RobertGakumu We expect answers to write the answer to the question, not just give links to where the reader can find them. If you extracted the list of "upsets" and wrote them here this could be a good answer.